# spring mvc 3.0.6 @RequestMapping for two level url got 404

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am using spring mvc 3.0.6. here is my code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/staff")
public class StaffController extends BaseController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView goStaffIndex(Model model) throws Exception{
        model.addAttribute("staff", new Staff());
        return new ModelAndView("staff/staffIndex","model",model);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/newStaff",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addStaff(Model model) throws Exception{
        model.addAttribute("staff", new Staff());
        return "staff/newStaff";
        //return new ModelAndView("staff/newStaff","model",model);
    }
}
```

- first method work fine.
- problem in second method, when i send a request:http://localhost:8080/mvc/staff/newStaff.do. dispatcher send request to addStaff() method, it is also fine. return is also fine. because debugging message told me it fine.

**message:**

- 20:16:30,648 INFO [stdout] DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView] -Forwarding to resource [WEB-INF/views/staff/newStaff.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'staff/newStaff'
- 20:16:30,648 INFO [stdout] DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - Successfully completed request

**however, page got a 404 error. but debug console without any error or warn.**

when i remove class @RequestMapping and change some code, such as:

```
public class StaffController extends BaseController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/staff",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView goStaffIndex(Model model) throws Exception{
        model.addAttribute("staff", new Staff());
        return new ModelAndView("staff/staffIndex","model",model);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/newStaff",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addStaff(Model model) throws Exception{
        model.addAttribute("staff", new Staff());
        return "staff/newStaff";
        //return new ModelAndView("staff/newStaff","model",model);
    }
}
```

after this, i send new request(with only one level url):http://localhost:8080/mvc/newStaff.do. working fine!!!!
any resolution or i mistaking something?

i am using jbossAS 7.0

Comment: Did you try either (a) putting the view one level deeper, in /staff/staff/newStaff.jsp, or (b) using an absolute path to the JSP?

Comment: thanks Dave..you show me a good idea for test..yes,when i use absolute path to JSP, it works..i returned to check my InternalResourceViewResolver configuration, the prefix = WEB-INF/views/, combining suggestion of cfontes what i changed to prefix = /WEB-INF/views/...working fine.thanks..

Comment: No problem :) If an answer didn't work, by the way, it wouldn't be accepted--it will confuse future visitors. It wasn't clear to me if you meant it worked or it didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a / in front of the staff to get the application context root

try this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/staff**")
public class StaffController extends BaseController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView goStaffIndex(Model model) throws Exception{
        model.addAttribute("staff", new Staff());
        return new ModelAndView("staff/staffIndex","model",model);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/staff/newStaff**",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addStaff(Model model) throws Exception{
        model.addAttribute("staff", new Staff());
        return "/staff/newStaff";            
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for cfontes reply..i modify code as you writed,  here still has the same problem...-_-!

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Cristiano is almost right. The only thing that was left behind is another bar before **:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/staff/**")
public class StaffController extends BaseController {
...
```